# Destination not writable on Fedora 17 using php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to upload files and am getting a destination not writeable error EVEN THOUGH the directory is chmodded 777

```
            $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $path=APPLICATION_PATH."/tmp";
            // die($path);
            $adapter->setDestination($path);
```

Following is the directory tree

```
/var                755
   /www             755
       /attendance  777 
            /tmp   <-- writeable 777
```

This is a really wierd error. In the past, after chmodding, the error generally went away. This is a local server(Fedora 17)

PHP Version 5.4.17

Apache/2.2.23 (Fedora)

php safe mode is off, atleast there is no entry in config files, nor could I see it anywhere in the phpinfo();

I've been trying for 8 hours, but no cigar, not even a Dunhill

Comment: what about the rest of the directories in APPLICATION_PATH? just because `tmp` is writeable doesn't mean much. it'd be like having a cardboard box of treasure inside a bank vault. the box is easy to open, but the vault isn't.

Comment: everything is writeable i did chmod -R /var/www/attendance which contains application>>tmp

Comment: this is a really wierd error